# Comparing date with date and time, gives unexpected result

Tags: php, datetime

While there are a lot of posts on how to compare two dates, I couldn't find related one.

Consider this:

```
$x = new \DateTime('2018-08-27');
$y = new \DateTime('2018-08-28');

$interval = $x->diff($y);

$diff = $interval->d; // 1 - fine
```

This returns the difference between two dates - 1 day, which is expected and correct.

But for now, consider the case, when the first object has date and time in it, while the second one hasn't.

```
$x = new \DateTime('2018-08-27 09:33:45');
$y = new \DateTime('2018-08-28');

$interval = $x->diff($y);

$diff = $interval->d; // 0 - wrong, expecting 1
```

I can solve this, but I want to avoid dirty hacks and workarounds to achieve this (i.e like trimming time). Is there any native way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `new \DateTime` with no time specified defaults to midnight, so there is only `14:26:15` between your two dates, which is less than one day. Hence `$interval->d = 0`. You will need to use [`setTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) to ensure both times are at midnight e.g.

```
$interval = $x->setTime(0,0,0)->diff($y->setTime(0,0,0));
```